# how to set cookies in curl using LIB_http

Tags: php, cookies, curl, screen-scraping, web-crawler

I'm receiving cookies message again & again while scraping the page manta.com
message is
Array ( [FILE] =>
Oops.
Before you can move on, please activate your browser cookies.

I am using cookies like this

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, CURL_TIMEOUT);    // Timeout
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, WEBBOT_NAME);   // Webbot name
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target);             // Target site
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $ref);            // Referer value
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, FALSE);           // Minimize logs
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);    // No certificate
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '10.1.11.11:8080');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);     // Follow redirects
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 4);             // Limit redirections to four
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);     // Return in string
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
```

Comment: @balmy not sure how useful it is to fix a single minor typo on an 8 year old low-quality question...

Answer (score -1):

You cannot easily scrape manta.com. They have an anti-bot system that stops bot activity even if you masquerade your agent. I believe you can still crawl them, but it will take time and a lot of ingenuity.

Comment: you are right but this is what i need.. an other way to get in side manta